Error while extending session in AuthJS v5
I've been working on extending the session in authjs v5 using callbacks to implement role-based authorization. I aim to assign a role to the token generated and then pass it to the session. The role is defined in the User Model in Prisma Schema as an enum with values user or admin.
Here is the relevant code from my auth.ts file:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import authConfig from "@/auth.config";
import {PrismaAdapter} from '@auth/prisma-adapter';
import { getUserById } from "./data/user";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";


export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  //EXTENDING SESSION USING CALLBACKS
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({token}) {
      //sub here refers to id
      if (!token.sub) return token;

      const existingUser = await getUserById(token.sub);

      if (!existingUser) return token;

      // Add user role to the token
      token.role = existingUser.role;
      return token;
   },
    async session({token, session}) {
      //sub here refers to id
      if (token.sub && session.user) {
        console.log({
          sessionToken : token
        });
        session.user.id = token.sub;
        session.user.role = token.role;
      }
      return session;
    },

  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  session: {strategy: "jwt"},
  ...authConfig,
});

However, I'm encountering the following TypeScript error:
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/**",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2339",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Property 'role' does not exist on type '{ id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; emailVerified: Date | null; image: string | null; password: string | null; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; }'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 20,
    "startColumn": 33,
    "endLineNumber": 20,
    "endColumn": 37
}


I suspect this issue arises because TypeScript doesn't recognize the role property on the token object. I tried authjs docs but they were no good. I've tried extending the DefaultJWT interface and session interface in next-auth module but that was of no help as well, the error persisted. How can I correctly type the role property to resolve this error and achieve the desired functionality?
Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've been able to resolve the user the prisma adpater was not able to access role column from the schema.prisma model. I redefined it in the node modules in types.d.ts and now it's working fine completely.
